# UTF-8 char is not showing well in <td> elements

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8

I have a strange problem...

I have the following string:

```
$sString = "This is my encoded string &eacute; &agrave;";
```

First, I remove html entities:

```
$sString = html_entity_decode($sString, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

What I want is to split this string properly to show each char in a different column of the same table's line.

Well, logically, I used:

```
$aString = str_split($sString) // Fill an array with each char
```

It doesn't work. It show in box the char as I didn't used html_entity_decode...

So, I decided to try the following:

```
   for($i = 0; $i < 16; $i++) {
     echo "<td>";
     echo $sLine1[$i];
     echo "</td>";
   }
```

It works **BUT** special chars as showed as a ? in a black box (encoding problem).

Where it's really strange, it's that when I **don't** put it in `<td>` elements, it shows well and there's **no** encoding problems !

My HTML page contains the charset to UTF-8 and is correctly formated (with doctype, html, body, etc...)

I have to admit that at this point, I've no idea from where this problem comes...

**UPDATE**

I just realized that when I show char by char outside the `<td>`, it doesn't work either. The encoded char needs to be by pair to work !
It's a problem for me because the string comes from a database, and special chars won't always be at the same place !

Exemple:

This will show the encoding problem char:

```
$sString = "Paëlla";
echo $sString[3];
```

But in this way, it will show the **ë**:

```
$sString = "Paëlla";
echo $sString[3];
echo $sString[4];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str_split` split the string on bytes. But in UTF-8, characters like é and à are encoded on a sequence of 2 bytes. You need to use mbstring to be UTF-8 aware.

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

function mb_str_split($string, $length = 1) {
    $ret = array();
    $l = mb_strlen($string);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $l; $i += $length) {
        $ret[] = mb_substr($string, $i, $length);
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Same if you apply `[offset]` to a string: you get a byte, not a character if the charset of the string may encode a character on more than a byte. In this case, use `mb_substr`.

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

echo mb_substr("Paëlla", 2, 1);
```

Comment: Up to 4 bytes in fact.

Answer (score 0):

Some adding to dinesh123 answer:

- Try to trim html strip_tags before you get a string ($sString)
- Check a file encoding
- Try to set header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8") in start of file